# ERROR: function plpython_call_handler() does not exist (PostreSQL, python)

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, plpython

I am a very begginer to SQL and am trying to create a trigger function for my postgreSQL db which will execute a python function using postgresql-plpython.9.5:

```
CREATE PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE "plpython" HANDLER plpython_call_handler;
CREATE FUNCTION process_all_or_apart() RETURNS text AS 
' 
#some python code
'
LANGUAGE "plpython";
CREATE TRIGGER trigger2
BEFORE INSERT ON some_data

EXECUTE PROCEDURE process_all_or_apart();
```

Although I have postgresql-plpython as an extension in my db, it get the same error:

```
"ERROR:  function plpython_call_handler() does not exist"
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There can be more issues:

1. PLPython doesn't exists more - Postgres suspports PLPythonu language only.

   try to create language only wit statement:

   ```
   CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu;
   ```
2. Maybe you are missing packages postgresql-plython or postgresql-plpython3